# Is there an adjective for people who prefer seeing diagrams rather than reading words?

Tags: word-choice

I have a friend who prefer seeing diagrams rather than reading words. Is there an adjective to represent his character?

Comment: I use *visualist* for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In educational circles, there is a term *visual learner*

> **Three Primary Learning Styles**
> Although a combination of strategies are used to help us learn and process data, individuals function with a dominate style for learning new information.  The primary learning styles are visual, auditory, and kinesthetic.
> Visual learners learn by seeing, auditory learners learn by hearing, and kinesthetic learners learn by doing.
> [Life and Learning](https://www.lifeandlearning.net/learning-styles-visual-learner-auditory-learner-kinesthetic-learner/)

[image]

Comment: wow. the site at the end of that link is horrible. you'd think people talking about visual learning would make something you could see.

Comment: Unreadably low contrast

Comment: Excuse me, additional question: And what is the name for people who learn by reading?

Comment: I don't know about that particular site ... but some forms of dislexia are aggravated by black-and-white high-contrast texts, and helped by soothing, subtle shades.  Or, some people just have no expertise in making web pages...

Comment: "I hear and I forget. I see and I remember. I do and I understand." (then Confucius is an visual-kinesthetic learner).

Comment: You left out "tactile" -- related to both visual and kinesthetic, but not the same thing.

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.

Comment: The link prompting these comments no longer exists (9+ years later).